# Swift Diffable datasource will crash when Firebase .observe() updates values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I am building an app where a user can read articles. Each article is written by an author, so, on the article view, when the user clicks on the author's profile picture it navigates to the Author's profile view.

In the Author Profile view, there is a "Follow" button, and in the same view, there are the statistics of the Author (ex. how many articles he/she wrote, how many followers they have, etc.). Something very close to this:

[image]

When the author profile view loads, everything is OK. But as soon as the user touches the "Follow" button, the app crashes with the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Section identifier count does not match data source count. This is most likely due to a hashing issue with the identifiers.'

These are the steps I follow:

1. User in the Author Profile view
2. User sees the "Follow" button and the stats showing how many users are following the author
3. Say the author has 10 followers. The user touches the "Follow" button
4. Behind the scenes, I go into Firebase, get the author, and add the userID into an array of strings: followers: ["asdm132123", "asdadsa12931", "!123123jsdfjsf"] by using .observeSingleEvent() and setValue()
5. Then I read the data using the **.observe()** method of Firebase, to update the button state from "Follow" --> "Following" and increase the followers' value from "10" --> "11"

Edit: Code part:

```
enum AuthorProfileSection {
    case details
    case stats
    case articles
}
```

Datasource creation:

```
func configureDataSource() -> UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<AuthorProfileSection, AnyHashable> {
 
    let dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<AuthorProfileSection, AnyHashable>(collectionView: collectionView) { (collectionView, indexPath, object) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
 
        
        if let object = object as? Author {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AuthorDetailsCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AuthorDetailsCell
            cell.configure(with: object)
            return cell
        }
        
        
        if let object = object as? AuthorStatsForAuthorProfile {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AuthorStatCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AuthorStatCell
            cell.configure(with: object)
            return cell
        }
        
        
        if let object = object as? Article {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: AuthorArticleCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! AuthorArticleCell

            cell.configure(with: object)
            return cell
        }
        
        return nil
    }
 
    return dataSource
}
```

Updating snapshot

```
fileprivate func updateSnapshot(animated: Bool = false) {
    
    guard let authorUID = authorUID else { return }

    Firebase.Database.database().fetchSelectedAuthorProfileData( authorUID: authorUID, fromArticleUID: self.articleUID) { authorProfileSection in
        
        var snapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
        
        // sections
        snapshot.appendSections([.details, .stats, .articles])
        snapshot.appendItems([authorProfileSection.details], toSection: .details)
        snapshot.appendItems(authorProfileSection.stats ?? [], toSection: .stats)
        snapshot.appendItems(authorProfileSection.articles ?? [], toSection: .articles)

        self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
    }
}
```

And the cell:

```
class AuthorStatCell: UICollectionViewCell, SelfConfiguringCell {

    typealias someType = AuthorStatsForAuthorProfile

    static var reuseIdentifier = "AuthorStatCell"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        buildUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    func configure(with data: AuthorStatsForAuthorProfile) {
        print(data)
    }

    fileprivate func buildUI() {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.20, green: 0.83, blue: 0.60, alpha: 1.00)
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
    }
}
```

And this is the result (in red the part that changes if I touch the "follow" button):

[image]

Here is where the app crashes. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to show the code that creates your snapshot and how you generate the identifiers for your section items.

Comment: @Paulw11 here you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect, the issue is inside updateSnapshot() you are getting the current snapshot and adding 3 new sections to it every time you touch follow button

```
var snapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
// sections
snapshot.appendSections([.details, .stats, .articles])
```

try this

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<AuthorProfileSection, AnyHashable>()
```

Or if you are calling another func like createSnapshot Before updateSnapshot then just try removing the line of appendSections

```
var snapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
// sections
// remove it
//snapshot.appendSections([.details, .stats, .articles])

snapshot.appendItems([authorProfileSection.details], toSection: .details)
snapshot.appendItems(authorProfileSection.stats ?? [], toSection: .stats)
snapshot.appendItems(authorProfileSection.articles ?? [], toSection: .articles)

self.dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animated)
```

I’m not sure 100%  about it bcs I just on my phone rn

Comment: Thank you for your input! After using var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<AuthorProfileSection, AnyHashable>() it started working with 2 caveats:  1) If I tried to press the "Follow" button again it crashed with the error "Fatal: supplied item identifiers are not unique" --> I fixed this by providing a unique id to every model involved. 2) Now, each time I press the "follow" button it reloads all data and looks like it stacks Stats sections and then goes back to normal. The more times I press the button the longer it takes to reload the data. Weird.

Comment: So it turns out the initializing my arrays of data prior calling Firebase .observe() method, caused the arrays to append the same data over and over again (I believe because I was not removing the observe). Hence the stack of section each time I pressed the "Follow" button.